# asp.net mvc 2 - return JavaScript with View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, view, controller

using ASP.NET MVC 2 I have a navigation menu inside my Master Page. In the navigation menu, I am trying add a class to the  that the current page relates to (i.e., home page will add class="active" to the Home button). I'm trying to consider scalability and the fact that I don't want to change individual pages if the navigation changes later.

The only way I can think of doing this is:

1. Add JavaScript to each individual View that will add the class when the DOM is ready
2. Return JavaScript when return View() occurs

on point (2), I am unsure how to do. Thus far I have been doing the following in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["message"] = JavaScript("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> $(document).ready(function () { console.log('hi hi hi'); }); </script>");

        return View();
    }
```

but in my view, when I call:

```
<%: ViewData["message"] %>
```

I get: *System.Web.Mvc.JavaScriptResult* as the result

Would you guys have any ideas on

- How to solve the navigation menu problem, other than the solutions I've listed
- return JavaScript along with your view from the Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code, save a string in the ViewData["message"] variable:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["message"] = "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> $(document).ready(function () { console.log('hi hi hi'); }); </script>";

    return View();
}
```

and then render it on the page with <%= %> and not <%: %>:

```
<%= ViewData["message"] %>
```

Comment: strange. I could have SWORN I tried that. I know that using <%: %> will basically say HTML.Encode()... but than what does the <%= %> do?

Comment: also, would you have an idea to on how to solve the navigation menu probelem, other than the solutions I've listed?

Comment: <%: %> does Html.Encode and <%= %> doesn't. 
For navigation menus I generally recommend using ASP.NET's navigation capabilities with sitemaps and all. Read more about it. I think the next page will be a good start: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/providing-website-navigation-with-sitemaps-cs

Answer (score 0):

```
public JavaScriptResult Index() 
{
    return JavaScript("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> $(document).ready(function () { console.log('hi hi hi'); }); </script>"); 
}
```